# Уведомление при изменение рабочей APK-файла

Tags: android, apk

При изменение новой версии APK-файла происходит уведомление:

> APK-файл, который нельзя обновить ВНИМАНИЕ! Пользователи этого
>   APK-файла не смогут установить APK, добавленные в новую версию
>   приложения.

И выдается совет: Убедитесь, что все новые APK-файлы добавлены в эту версию приложения. Не могу понять, что это значит?! Кто с таким уведомление сталкивался? И на что оно влияет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно это означает, что поле `minSdk` в манифесте изменилось в сторону увеличения. То есть юзеры со старыми девайсами не смогут установить у себя ваше обновление, потому что APK требует более новый API level.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А почему это уведомление пропадает, если перенести старый фал из Деактивровать в Сохранить?